# LWC Design Attribure is not working on the Record Page

Tags: lightning-web-components, design-attributes

I'm working on a LWC trying to make it reusable so need to set Design Attributes to get values dynamically and use them in the component.

I have got following target configs in the js-meta file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="urn:metadata.tooling.soap.sforce.com" fqn="nufRelatedList">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage,lightning__AppPage,lightning__HomePage">
            <property name="strTitle" type="String" label="Title" default="Test Mo" description="Enter the title"/>
            <property name="objectName" type="String" label="Object Name" description="Enter the object name"/>
            <property name="fields" type="String" label="Fields List" description="Enter the field API names separated by coma. Do not enter more than 4 fields"/>
            <property name="relatedFieldApiName" type="String" label="Account Plan Look Up Field API Name" description="Enter the Account Plan look up field API name here"/>
            <property name="sobjectApiName" type="String" label="Object Label" description="Enter the Object name from where related data need to be displayed"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

and the following in the Js controller

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from "lwc";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import NufRelatedListHelper from "./nufRelatedListHelper";
import {loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import RelatedListResource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/relatedListResource';

export default class NufRelatedList extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @track state = {}
    @api sobjectApiName;
    @api relatedFieldApiName;
    @api numberOfRecords = 6;
    @api sortedBy;
    @api sortedDirection = "ASC";
    @api rowActionHandler;
    @api fields;
    @api strTitle;
    @api objectName;
    @api fieldsList;
```

its getting the attribute from only one relatedFieldApiName; others are coming a undefined I also have tried with default still coming as undefined.

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure, you are not overwriting the attribute values inside the component?

Comment: No I'm not overwriting I just tried with only one property still getting the same issue but its working on the page builder not in the real time.

Comment: Can you please explain, when it is not working? If possible please add some code snippet by editing the question.